# Bulk insert not working as expected

Tags: c#, mysql, rows, bulkinsert

I have 2 tables in 2 different server. I called the one is local and another one is remote table. For some reasons, I want to do bulk insert to remote table and use the local data as source. In PHPMYADMIN, i have checked both its totalRows.

```
    TABLE   |  ROWS  
  -----------------------
    LOCAL   |  1111
    REMOTE  |  0
```

I expect the remote table to have the same rows as local table. But it's not working as expected. After did bulk insert, it returns :

```
    TABLE   |  ROWS  
  -----------------------
    LOCAL   |  1111
    REMOTE  |  64
```

I don't know why it happens. I did the same way for another tables for 2 different server too and it works as what i'm expected. Maybe you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

So you used the same code to bulk insert in 2 different remote servers and it works perfectly?

Are you using LOAD DATA INFILE? Or you are just running multiple insert queries?

If you're using LOAD DATA INFILE, you wanna make sure that the path to the file is correct.